# Prevent navigation drawer toggle from sliding to the left when opening (Material)

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

How can I prevent the navigation drawer toggle from sliding to the left / right when opening / closing the navigation drawer?
-> Like Material

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer_indicator_new, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
```

Comment: override `onDrawerOpened` without calling the `super.onDrawerOpened(view)`

Comment: I don't have it written in onDrawerOpened

public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name_big);


                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

Comment: do you call syncState?

Comment: Yeah, just removed it, maybe that works :)

Comment: It's showing the standard back button now, I imagine I have to set the back button to my drawer resource?

Comment: Are you using ActionBarDrawerToggle from appcompat-v7?

Comment: v4 if I remember well